# How to test values on scope of directive with inline controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the following directive which I want to unit test:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('gameApp')
  .directive('gmGravatar', gmGravatar);

gmGravatar.$inject = ['$routeParams', 'playersService'];

function gmGravatar() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<img gravatar-src="gravatar.email" alt="" id="gravatar" class="img-rounded" style="margin: auto; display: block;">',
    controller: function($routeParams, playersService) {
      var vm = this;
      var playerId = $routeParams.playerId;
      playersService.getPlayerInfo({
        playerId: playerId
      }).$promise.then(function(player) {
        vm.email = player.email;
      });
    },
    controllerAs: 'gravatar'
  };
  return directive;
}
```

I've successfully setup my test spec and got my first assertion to pass. However, I'm struggling with how to test `vm.email`:

```
'use strict';

describe('gmGravatar directive', function() {
  var element;
  var scope;
  var $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('gameApp'));
  beforeEach(module('templates'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, _$httpBackend_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = '<gm-gravatar></gm-gravatar>';
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/players/playerInfo').respond(200, '');
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('should replace the element with the appropriate content', function() {
    expect(element.html()).toContain('<img gravatar-src="gravatar.email"');
    expect(scope.email).toEqual('joe@example.com');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `expect(scope.gravatar.email).toEqual('joe@example.com');`

You can also try `expect(element.scope().gravatar.email).toEqual('joe@example.com');`